# Android Emulators for Specific Devices

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been searching for device specific default emulators to use for Android app development. Does anyone know of a site, database, repository, or whatever with downloadable emulators that are set up to mimic specific devices (For example: HTC Hero emulator or Galaxy Tab Emulator). It would be a lot nicer if the manufacturers had emulators available to download so that you can test your app against their specific device. Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: If you do find such an emulator, that mimics the real devices 99.9% **including the microphone section**, please let us know. +1 for raising an important issue.

Comment: I'd like to leave this as an open question and collect a list of links to every major manufacturer's primary phones. I may start a database of them if I can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galaxy Tab Emulator can be downloaded straight from the SDK Manager.

Go into Available Packages -> Third party Add-ons -> Samsung Electronics -> GALAXY Tab by Samsung Electronics., Android API8, revision 1

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to find that one (although I was having some issues communicating with the Samsung Android repository)

Answer (score 2):

Motorola does have such emulators and/or skins.  Check out http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if any of the other manufacturers do? (I'm primarily needing HTC and Samsung ones since those are what the final devices will be for this particular business). If so, do you have links for them?

Comment: I don't.  I take it Google doesn't locate any?

Comment: Google spit back a bunch of people with similar questions, mainly pointing at the Motorola ones (props to them for actually helping developers support their products!) and some outdated links for older phones. Seeing how much of an issue this is, I'm possibly going to try to put together a big collection of them and host them on my personal website (I'll post a link once I finish everything)

Comment: This link is dead as of June 2018

Answer (score 1):

There are some HTC skins [here](http://www.android.encke.net), but they are kind of outdated. There are also Nexus One and Nexus S skins [here](http://heikobehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins) with a short tutorial that look decent.

Edit: Just to point out, these are not made by the respective manufacturers.